# how would i start a TimepickerDialog from a DialogFragment in android?

Tags: android, timepicker, dialogfragment

long story short when the user clicks a button in my DialogFragment, i want a TimePickerDialog fragment to pop up, then after the time is set, the user returns the the previous fragment. would all of this be managed from within the activity, or the parent fragment, and what would the steps be to do such a thing? if somebody could point me in the right direction i'd really appreciate it, i havn't been able to find a straight answer anywhere. thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```
package com.whatever.date;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class DatePicker extends DialogFragment {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity(),
                c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }
}
```

And this to your main activity onClick method

```
DialogFragment f = new DatePicker();
f.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "TAG");
```

Comment: there's only one event listener that creates a fragment and it's the main CustomDialogFragment. within the main CustomDialogFragment theres a button "set time" that would render a TimePickerDialog. kinda a dialog inception lol would subclassing the CustomDialogFragment give me the results i need?

Comment: the CustomDialogFragment has a button. When you click this, it opens date picker. Right? Or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: no that's correct, just to me it seems, that since CustomDialogFragment will render a new TimePickerDialog shouldn't the CustomDialogFragment be responsible for starting it, or is that not correct?

Comment: no, I think you should just make a new DialogFragment, avoid the spaghetti code here. Plus, the CustomDialogFragment has a button, which will be redrawn

Comment: okay so let me see if i got this straight: create a method in Activity to handle the TimePickerFragment, then pass the activity reference into CustomDialogFragment, and on some event call the activities method inside of CustomDialogFragment?

Comment: yes, that is the plan. no wait, why do you need the activity reference?

Comment: i'm getting a "cannot resolve method" error. i've passed in the activity to CustomDialogFragment and set it to a field variable, then called mActivityVariable.methodForStartingTimePicker(), and getActivity().methodForStartingTimePicker()

Comment: cast the activity. ((MyActivity)getActivity).myMethod, try that

Comment: i used the activity reference so i can call mActivityReferenceVariable.methodForStartingTimePicker();

Comment: HA! didn't even think of that! thank you a lot friend